# xcode 8 storyboard slow in macbook pro 2016

Tags: xcode, performance, storyboard, xcode8, macos-sierra

I have macbook pro 2016 15inch using mac os 10.12.3 and xcode 8.2.1. 
But in storyboard mode when I click the button in viewcontroller in storyboard. The mouse pointer loading 3 second then focus the component. But i try open that project in older macbook pro(13inch 2015 run same os version and xcode version) then action click button like this take 0.3second.
Any one have same issue. I had try reinstall os but it still. I think it is problem about xcode. Thank you

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on my MBP 15 (2016) with XCode 8.3. The storyboard takes some time for load which is crazy for such a powerful MacBook.